Build issue: Conflicts with Google Protobuf dependency with existing Firebase dependencies
Facing Issue when adding -
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:3.44.0' library in gradle facing error as shown in image
Gradle Error code below -

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-2.41.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.41.0) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)

2.Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'google/protobuf/empty.proto' from inputs:
3.Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'google/protobuf/empty.proto'.
I have tried to exclude module also but in that case i am unable to import required classes.
implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:3.44.0'){
exclude module : 'proto-google-common-protos'
exclude module : 'protolite-well-known-types'
exclude module : 'protobuf-java'
exclude module : 'protobuf-javalite'
}
Below is the function and screenshot where i am facing error -
private fun searchProduct(
    segmentedImage: Bitmap,
    x_min: Int,
    y_min: Int,
    x_max: Int,
    y_max: Int,
    half_sku: String
): FloatArray {
    try {
        // Load the credentials from the service account key JSON file
        val credentials: GoogleCredentials =
            GoogleCredentials.fromStream(context.assets.open("caratlane-v4-c3d8e96bfa95.json"))
        val settings: ImageAnnotatorSettings = ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build()
        Log.d("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOLLLLLLLLL", credentials.toString())
        try {
            ImageAnnotatorClient.create(settings).use { client ->
                // Convert the segmented image to ByteString
                val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                segmentedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
                val imgBytes =
                    ByteString.copyFrom(baos.toByteArray())

                // Create an image request
                val image: Image = Image.newBuilder()
                    .setContent(imgBytes)
                    .build()
                val feature: Feature = Feature.newBuilder()
                    .setType(Feature.Type.PRODUCT_SEARCH)
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .build()
                //                BoundingPoly boundingPoly = BoundingPoly.newBuilder()

//                        .addVertices(Vertex.newBuilder().setX(x_min).setY(y_min).build())
//                        .addVertices(Vertex.newBuilder().setX(x_max).setY(y_min).build())
//                        .addVertices(Vertex.newBuilder().setX(x_max).setY(y_max).build())
//                        .addVertices(Vertex.newBuilder().setX(x_min).setY(y_max).build())
//                        .build();
val imageContext: ImageContext = ImageContext.newBuilder()
.setProductSearchParams(
ProductSearchParams.newBuilder()
.setProductSet("projects/caratlane-v4/locations/asia-east1/productSets/cl-vs-prod-v6")
.addProductCategories("apparel-v2")
.setFilter("half_sku=$half_sku") //                                .setBoundingPoly(boundingPoly)
.build()
)
.build()
                val request: AnnotateImageRequest = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addFeatures(feature)
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setImageContext(imageContext)
                    .build()

                // Perform the request
                val responses: List<AnnotateImageResponse> =
                    client.batchAnnotateImages(listOf(request))
                        .getResponsesList()
                for (response in responses) {
                    if (response.hasError()) {
                        Log.e(
                            "ProductSearch",
                            "Error: " + response.getError().getMessage()
                        )
                    }

                    // Parse and handle the response
                    val results: ProductSearchResults = response.getProductSearchResults()
                    var resultText = ""
                    val floatarr = FloatArray(10)
                    var i = 0
                    for (result in results.getResultsList()) {
                        resultText += result.getScore()
                        floatarr[i] = result.getScore()
                        i++
                        resultText += "\n"
                    }
                    //result.setText("\nVisual Search Scores:\n$resultText")
                    return floatarr
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOLLLLLLLLL", e.toString())
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("ProductSearch", "Error searching product", e)
    }
    return FloatArray(0)
}


